# Boss wants to buy me a car - but I'm quitting soon

Tags: management, job-change, quitting

I'm planning to quit my job in a week or two after singing a contract with another company. At my current employer I have a full-time contract and at my next job I will get 6 month probation. The new job is in another city so I will need to relocate but before I can do that I must first buy a car. I was planing to get a small loan from the bank before I quit because I don't think I can get one on a 6 month contract. To do that I need my employer to sign a paper that says that he won't fire me in the near future. Today I brought my boss the paper to sign and I told that I need a loan for a car (in hindsight a mistake). The boss told me that she want to buy me a personal car as a gratitude for all the work I have done.

What do I do now? I can't quit now before I sign the contract with the next company. I can't tell my boss that I will quit soon because I don't know if she'll sign the necessary paper. How how do I reject her offer?

Country: Croatia

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77283/discussion-on-question-by-codebreaker-boss-wants-to-buy-me-a-car-but-im-quitt).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> What do I do now?

From an ethical perspective, do you think its right to let your current employer buy you a car, and then you quit shortly after?  **I think you know this is not a good move** long term on your part, and will most definitely will have burned the bridge to this employer.

Your best bet is to **refuse the gift graciously**, and have your current employer sign the paperwork needed so you can get the loan for the automobile.  You could say something like "*I really appreciate the offer, but that is simply too much and I cannot accept it.*"

Then just make the regular loan payments as expected so there is no trouble, and move on to your new role peacefully.

Comment: +1 Accepting a gift of a car (!!!) from your boss sounds like a terrible idea anyway.

Comment: Hypothetically, would your answer be the same if the current employer were a large corporation offering the OP a cash bonus?  If not, why?

Comment: @James Of course the answer would be different because that's a different question. Your boss personally buying you a car is not the same thing as your company issuing you a bonus. The bonus is fungible. I can exchange it for whatever I want once received. While technically one could sell the car for cash, then buy something else, the implications of doing so and the effect it would have on your interaction with the boss at work are quite different.

Comment: @iheanyi:  I re-read the question and see that "The boss told me that she want to buy me a personal car...".  I assumed that meant that the boss was buying the car with company funds.  I think you have assumed that the boss is buying the car with their personal cash because you say "boss personally buying you a car".  If your interpretation is correct then I agree that OP shouldn't accept the car.  If company funds were being used to buy the car "as a gratitude for all the work I have done", then I think OP should take the car.

Comment: @James even if it's the boss buying the car with company funds - there's the issue of it being given as a car instead of just cash. Cash can be spent however the recipient chooses. A car cannot. As I said, the fact that the "gift" is in car form has specific ramifications which a cash bonus from a corporation will not have.

Comment: @James, your hypothetical question would be equivalent if the corporation was giving a bonus, but required the employee to sign an agreement saying that it will only be spent on purchasing a vehicle whose primary use is for transportation to work.

Comment: @iheanyi:  The OP says they are quitting in one or two weeks and that they want a car.  Their boss is offering (I assume with company funds) to buy them a "personal" car for gratitude for previous work done.  My interpretation is that a "personal" car will belong to the OP.  Perhaps your interpretation is that the car will still belong to the company?

Comment: @James The boss doesn't know the OP is quitting. All the boss knows is that OP is a great worker and has expressed a need for a car which presumably will facilitate travel to work. The boss isn't buying the OP a car that the OP will then give to someone else. The boss is buying a car with the expectation that the OP will use it regularly for purposes that enhance their work performance (reducing stress/time away due to current commute). So, while the car won't belong to the company, the company strongly expects to get benefit from said car.

Comment: @James look at it this way, my partner expressed a desire for an expensive item, I purchased that item for my partner (so it doesn't belong to me), then my partner takes that item and immediately leaves me for someone else, how should that make me feel? What kind of account will I give should someone in the future ask me for a recommendation about that person's character, work ethic, etc? A bonus is more akin to splurging on an expensive meal. There's a much different set of expectations attached.

Answer (score 5):

If you're moving to the city where your new employer is (so that you mostly need a car for moving), then simply **rent a car**, or pay a company to make the relocation for you.

Knowing that your life won't be over if your current boss doesn't give you the paperwork for your loan, you can simply tell her you're leaving, refuse her gift, and ask her to sign the paperwork anyway. Chances are, she will understand your reasons and sign it. If she takes the news badly and refuses to sign your papers, you will simply rent a car for your relocation.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that you're leaving for family reasons is going to dampen whatever ill will the manager might hold against you, so they'll be inclined to sign the papers. Whether it is legal for them to sign them knowing that you won't actually be employed for long is a different story.

Comment: Exactly this.  Tell her you're leaving soon for family reasons (don't get into details about any new job) and so you can't accept a personal car, then ask if she could sign the papers so you can buy your own.  (Assuming it's legal :P)

Comment: OP might not want to tell her that he's leaving before the contract for the new job is signed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already accepted the offer from your new employer and signed the contract, then you can be honest with your current boss, tell him you will be leaving the company and thank him for his offer.

The potential drawback is, of course, that he might sabotage you by not signing the paperwork for the bank. You will need to figure out whether you believe he would stoop to this. Then again, if he is so happy with you that he would gift you a car, it sounds like he would not quite sink so low.

If you *haven't* already signed the new contract, you should of course not be shopping for a new car - especially one that requires a loan.

Answer (score 0):

> The boss told me that she want to buy me a personal car as a gratitude for all the work I have done.

I would take it as a bonus! This gift is for all the hard work that you have done in the **past**. Let's say the car costs 15,000 credits and your boss gives you a bonus of 15,000 credits as appreciation for the work done in past, would you still deny the bonus?

I would work a couple months more if my employer gives me a bonus as courtesy and then move to better opportunities.

Comment: Can the down voters please provide a comment.

Comment: +1 - I've seen many highly rated answers to other similar questions recommending to make sure bonus is received before putting in two weeks notice.

Answer (score -2):

Aside from the question of whether it's ethical to accept a gift from your boss knowing you're going to quit, you're also planning to commit fraud.

You're presenting the bank paperwork that alleges certainty of employment (with your current employer) knowing full well that in a few weeks time you'll transition to a new employer who could basically sack you for no reason during a period of six months, which I assume would be the bulk of the loan term.

Don't lie to your bank. See if you can make do without a car, or maybe get a friend to be your guarantor, or perhaps stay with your current employer. I know you have your reasons, and the grass looks very green on the other side of the fence, but if you're willing to commit fraud to go there, then there are other ways to make money illegally.

Comment: The paperwork alleges that the employer has no intent to fire the employee, not that the employee won't quit his job or do something that causes him to get fired. -1.

Comment: It sounds like the paperwork is all about the employers current plans, not the employees plans, so no suggestion of fraud. Also plans change, on both sides.

Comment: Even if the paperwork presented to the boss isn't directly lying, the OP is clearly trying to mis-represent his future income to the bank. That may or may not be legal fraud, but it's definitely moral fraud, and banks tend to be really on top of noticing, spelling out, and banning loopholes like that.

Comment: @Brondahl He's not mis-representing his future income, except possibly _under_-representing it. The new job pays almost double the aomunt.

Comment: @iheanyi  From his own information in the question, OP knows that the bank wants this form as an indication that his employment future is stable, and he knows that he wouldn't get the loan if he only had a 6 month probation, yet he is bringing in a form which he knows misrepresents his employment

Comment: @cdkMoose If the bank wanted to guarantee that the loaner won't change employers, they could have specified this clearly in the loan contract. Such a contract would probably be illegal and nil in most EU countries though.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, bank is not necessarily concerned about changing employers, but they are looking for employment stability confirmation.  If OP is switching to a risky job opportunity(from the bank's perspective), they want to know.  OP is specifically aware of this *"because I don't think I can get one on a 6 month contract"* and is choosing to use his current employer (which he intends to leave) to hide that fact.  I'm not familiar with the specifics of EU law but this seems deceptive to me.

Comment: @cdkMoose 'they want to know'  Source needed.  Given that the bank has gone to the lengths to check with the employer that the job is stable, surely we must assume they could very well do the same for the employee.

Comment: @pipe If he's not trying to deceive the bank then he would have told them exactly what's happening and the situation would never have existed. I don't care whether it's illegal, or contractually valid - it IS deception. You can tell, from the way that he doesn't want the bank to know certain things.

Comment: @NPSF3000 source is OP: *"because I don't think I can get one on a 6 month contract"*

Comment: @NPSF3000,, I don't know exactly what the bank said to OP.  From my own experience, every non-srtudent loan I have ever applied for asked for paperwork as part of income verification.  Since I am not the only commenter raising this issue, I believe I am not alone in this.  The bank checked with this employer, because OP withheld the information that he intends to leave this employer.

Comment: @Brondahl Chances are the situation would never have existed indeed. I was in exactly this situation and I told the bank about my plan to switch jobs in the near future. I got the loan anyway. I suppose that's because **people who get fired are risky loaners, not people who change jobs**.

Comment: @cdkMoose if what the bank is actually concerned about is that his employment is stable, they should have him fill out such a form. Unless he's slavery is legal in Croatia, I can't see how the bank can assume an **employer's** intent to continuing employing someone is sufficient to ensure an **employee** won't change jobs to something the bank would not like. His fear that 6 month probation might disqualify him is immaterial, he's not the bank and clearly doesn't know their qualifying process. You're accusing him of thoughtcrime with what we know.

Comment: @iheanyi, I'm not accusing OP of anything.  The post clearly indicates knowledge that the 6 month probation job could block the ability to get the loan and OP is choosing to use an employer he intends to leave instead of the the job he expects to have.  OP knows the expectation and is choosing to sidestep anyway.

Comment: @cdkMoose but that's what is asked of him.  The bank isn't asking (as far as we know) whether or not he will have steady employment for the duration of the loan, but rather whether or not he has steady employment *now*.  You're inferring an argument that is not being made by the bank.  I recently got a car loan, it did not ask what my job *tomorrow* would be, but what it is *today*.

Comment: @cdkMoose the post does not indicate any such knowledge. It says `because I don't think I can get one on a 6 month contract.` That is a statement of opinion, not fact. Furthermore, even if it were fact, it still does not rise to what you are claiming, that there is something illegal about adjusting the timing of one's actions to get the best advantage. Would it be illegal to wait a few months for a promotion and new yearly salary before buying a car too? Your line of reasoning doesn't make sense.